# Why does 'TextField' break this class and freeze the program?

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble understanding why adding a TextField causes this class to break and freeze the program. When I remove it, the Unit class works perfectly. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

I have attempted to use the class in various areas of my code with minimal surrounding effects. Additionally, I have searched for similar issues on Google and thoroughly reviewed the Flutter documentation.

Thank you in advance!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Unit extends StatefulWidget {
  const Unit({super.key, required this.unitID});

  final String unitID;

  @override
  State<Unit> createState() => _UnitState();
}

class _UnitState extends State<Unit> {
  bool _active = false;

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _handleUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      _active = !_active;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double unitWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double unitHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final String unitID = widget.unitID;

    return Container(
      height: unitHeight * 0.2,
      width: unitWidth * 0.7,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 72, 72)),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 110, 110)),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          const Text('Unit name'),
          // ignore: unnecessary_string_interpolations
          Text('$unitID'),
          const TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[TextField in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IgG1.png)

[No TextField in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwKVP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put TextField in Expanded like this

```
Expanded(child: TextFormField()),
```

As far as I understand, the UI can't figure out what the width of the widget should be and stops.

Answer (score 0):

in your declaration for unitHeight, you assigned it a mediaQuery width instead, kindly modify it to:

```
double unitHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

complete code:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Unit extends StatefulWidget {
  const Unit({super.key, required this.unitID});

  final String unitID;

  @override
  State<Unit> createState() => _UnitState();
}

class _UnitState extends State<Unit> {
  bool _active = false;

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _handleUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      _active = !_active;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double unitWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    /// modify
    double unitHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final String unitID = widget.unitID;

    return Container(
      height: unitHeight * 0.2,
      width: unitWidth * 0.7,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 72, 72)),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 110, 110)),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
        Text('ID:$unitID'),
        const TextField(
          decoration:
              InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a small error in my code. Unfortunately, that's not the issue I'm encountering. The problem persists: it still renders only one of the two buttons, and then stops at the unit between them.